# check if row already exists if does not exist insert row otherwise show message

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, exists

```
String sql2="if not exists(select * FROM stock where productCode=?)\n" +
                    "Begin\n" +
                    "insert into stock "
                  + "(productName,quantity,currentQuantity,price,companyName,categoryName,productCode) "
                  + "values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)\n" +
                    "End";
            PreparedStatement pst2 = con.prepareStatement(sql2);
            pst2.setString(1,productCodeTextField.getText());
            pst2.setString(2,productNameTextField.getText());
            pst2.setString(3,quantityTextField.getText());
            pst2.setString(4,quantityTextField.getText());
            pst2.setString(5,priceTextField.getText());
            pst2.setString(6, (String) companyNameJComboBox.getSelectedItem());
            pst2.setString(7, (String) categoryNameJComboBox.getSelectedItem());
            pst2.setString(8,productCodeTextField.getText());
            int x=pst2.executeUpdate();
            if(x!=0){
                productCodeTextField.setText("");
                productNameTextField.setText("");
                quantityTextField.setText("");
                priceTextField.setText("");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Product entered");    
            }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Product already exists");
            }
```

I am successfully able to check for for already existing products before insertion but i am not able to populate the correct message on the basis of the query executed. The executeUpdate is always returning some value even when the insertion is not being done. How to fix this.

Comment: mysql and sql-server are two different rdbms. Please tag correct one.

Answer (score 2):

There is an easier solution that may work for you:

1. Throw away the first query that checks whether the entry already exists
2. Rewrite sql2 as follows:

   ```
   INSERT INTO stock 
   (productCode, productName, quantity, price, companyName, categoryName) 
   VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)
   WHERE NOT EXISTS 
       (SELECT * FROM stock WHERE productCode = ?)
   ```
3. Add:  `pst.setString(7, productCodeTextField.getText());`
4. `executeUpdate()` returns an `int` indicating the number of rows affected by the query.  Use this variable to determine if a row was added.  If the variable != 0 display success message.

Comment: On adding keyword "ignore" error message is showing saying Incorrect syntax near the keyword "into"

Comment: @MohitJoshi Please paste the complete String you entered that's generating the error.

Comment: insert ignore into stock (productCode, productName, quantity, price, companyName, categoryName) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)

Comment: @MohitJoshi You originally had this question tagged for mysql.  That SQL statement will work in mysql but not in SQL Server.  I'll write another answer for SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO stock 
(productCode, productName, quantity, price, companyName, categoryName) 
select ?,?,?,?,?,?
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT * FROM stock WHERE productCode = ?)
```

This is how it works for SQL Server. 3 and 4 points same as Coop answered